# Upload image to S3 python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to S3 through Python. My code looks like this:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import boto
from boto.s3.key import Key

def upload_to_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, file, bucket, key, callback=None, md5=None, reduced_redundancy=False, content_type=None):

    conn = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket, validate=False)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = key

    k.set_contents_from_file(file)

AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "...."
AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = "....."

filename = "images/image_0.jpg"
file = Image.open(filename)

key = "image"
bucket = 'images'

upload_to_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY, file, bucket, key)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.</Message> 
<RequestId>90593132BA5E6D6C</RequestId> 
<HostId>...</HostId></Error>
```

This code is based on the tutorial from this website: http://stackabuse.com/example-upload-a-file-to-aws-s3/

I have tried k.set_contents_from_file as well as k.set_contents_from_filename, but both don't seem to work for me.

The error says something about using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256, but I am not sure how to do that. Is there another way to solve this problem besides using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256? If anyone can help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you want to rewrite to use boto3, boto is perhaps no longer supported...

Comment: Yes! I used boto3 and it worked! @AndyHayden thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Just use:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')

client.upload_file('images/image_0.jpg', 'mybucket', 'image_0.jpg')
```

Try to avoid putting your credentials in the code. Instead:

- If you are running the code from an Amazon EC2 instance, simply assign an **IAM Role** to the instance with appropriate permissions. The credentials will automatically be used.
- If you are running the code on your own computer, use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command to store your credentials in a file, which will be automatically used by your code.

Comment: and if you are running the code locally in the Docker container, pass credentials as environment variables.